# Wireless network is disabled

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, realtek

After Ubuntu did an update today, I lost the ability to connect to wifi.  When I open network settings, It is enabled, but does not find any networks.  I started out the day on 18.04 and hoped that upgrading to 20.04 would fix it, but no luck.  I've been looking around for solutions all day, but can't find any answers.  Below is the information commonly requested:

lshw -c network:

```
*-generic DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: wlp7s0
       version: ff
       serial: 48:5f:99:81:69:95
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: bus_master vga_palette cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_pci driverversion=5.4.0-42-generic firmware=N/A latency=255 link=no maxlatency=255 mingnt=255 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:131 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:a4300000-a430ffff
```

rfkill list all:

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

sudo ifconfig wlp7s0 up

```
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation already in progress
```

lspci

```
....
07:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter (rev ff)
....
```

iwconfig

```
wlp7s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
```

dmesg | grep -i wlp7s0

```
[    3.550035] rtw_pci 0000:07:00.0: Firmware version 27.2.0, H2C version 13
[    3.841833] rtw_pci 0000:07:00.0 wlp7s0: renamed from wlan0
[    7.784115] rtw_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to poll offset=0x5 mask=0x2 value=0x0
[    7.784123] rtw_pci 0000:07:00.0: mac power on failed
[    7.784124] rtw_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to power on mac
```

Answer (score 1):

i've the same problem, but i downgrade the kernel (first you have to boot to other kernel, using "Advanced Options for Ubuntu" on Grub), then i check my wifi, if it's okay so i downgrade it using
`sudo apt-get remove linux-image-VERSION linux-header-VERSION`

It works for me :D

Comment: Do you have exactly same wireless chip and the same kernel version as the OP?

Comment: yes i have exactly same wireless chip and ubuntu 18.04, also got the same problem after i upgrade it. but i don't know the OP's kernel version.